# dojo 1.10 adding sort behaviour of CheckedMultiSelect

Tags: sorting, dojo

Hello everyone i am desperately trying to sort a CheckedMultiSelect with little luck, it seems that despite changing the order of the data in the store it is always displayed alphabetically.

Being relatively new to dojo i have tried to look around for a tutorial but alas i am having no joy.

Can someone explain to me how best to sort the data in a CheckedMultiSelect that is being populated by a Memory store?

Code:

```
var store = new Memory({'data', : data});
//where this is my CheckedMultiSelect box
this._set("store", store);
```

in my postCreate function i now do this:

```
this.options = this.store.query({}, {sort: [{attribute: "name", descending: "true"}]});
this._set("labelAttr", "name");
 console.log(this.options);
```

I can see both in firebug and in console that the data is in the right order however now i cannot see anything but checkboxes, there is a space where the value of that selection should be).

I dont know if this is going to help at all but this is the code that sets the data that populates the multi select, everything beforehand is just parsing of a string into the store object.

No matter what I do i cannot get the order to change, even changing the order of the elements in the stores data does not make a blind bit of difference, i am guessing there is some sort of behaviour that CheckedMultiSelect has in regards to sorting but it is just that; a guess.

Comment: Please post some of the relevant code. You may need to sort the list manually.

Comment: added the snipped of code which populates the store of my multiselectbox

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial?
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/sorting.html

Comment: adding additional code after having a night to sleep on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `sortByLabel: false`, then provide a `queryOptions` object (see example below).

As to why we'd need `sortByLabel`, see [_FormSelectWidget](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/_FormSelectWidget.js#L94):

```
    // sortByLabel: Boolean
    //      Flag to sort the options returned from a store by the label of
    //      the store.
    sortByLabel: true,
```

... Though there appear to be [plans to deprecate it](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/_FormSelectWidget.js#L355).

Here's the example:

```
var checkedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect ({
    dropDown: true,
    multiple: true,
    labelAttr: "label", // Need this to be able to use Memory directly
    sortByLabel: false, // Need this to override sort
    queryOptions: {     // Now, finally, specify sort order.
        sort: [
          {attribute:'sortByMeFirst'},
          {attribute:'sortByMeSecond', descending: true}
        ]
    },
    store: memoryStore
}, "dropdown");
```

See: [jsfiddle sorting a CheckedMultiSelect](http://jsfiddle.net/inanutshellus/2bdzde82/)

Comment: This was indeed the issue, after figuring to set this to false and then using query api all was well :)

Comment: I actually needed to do this myself and came back here, only to realize our solution was more complicated than it needed to be. I've updated the example and the JSfiddle. Hopefully it'll help someone.